# .Net Core 3.1 MSSQL backend in Docker setup: Docker-compose up producing connection failure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, connection

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        container_name: web_application
        depends_on:
            - medicalmgr
    
    medicalmgr:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: Pw@mm2021
            ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        container_name: mmm_mmsql_2019
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore && \
    dotnet publish -c Release -o out
    
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MedicalManager.dll"]
```

**Startup.cs 's**

```
public void CofigureServices(..){
      ....
       var server = Configuration["DBServer"] ?? "medicalmgr";
       var port = Configuration["DBPort"] ?? "1433";
       var user = Configuration["DBUser"] ?? "SA";
       var password = Configuration["DBPassword"] ?? "Pw@mm2021";
       var database = Configuration["Database"] ?? "MedicalManager";


       //var connectionStr = $"Server={server},{port};Initial Catalog={database};User ID= 
       //{user};Password={password}";
       var connectionStr = 
       @"Server=medicalmgr;Database=MedicalManager;User=sa;Password=Pw@mm2021;";
       services.AddDbContext<MedicalManagerDBContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStr)
       );}
```

**Error:**
Application startup exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Ref: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) _By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name._ Have you tried using `Server=mmm_mmsql_2019;` in your connection string?

Comment: The container name will not work for server name even though  they are by design  all containers having been in same  host machine  share the same  default  network unless specified.  Anyway,  here  is the source  code, https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development/pull/new/docker_mssql_con public access. If  you could see if you can connect. BTW, if the  .Net app  not  in docker but DB is, then it connects.  I need  both    to be in  Docker setup. Your help will be greatly  appreciated. Thanks  Dan Guzman

Comment: Dan  Guzman.  I resolved the issue with having asp.net core 3.2 app with mssql db both running in containerized solution. However, only when in container setup, post user Registering, the Login does not work. Any suggestion. Some redirection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var connectionStr = 
@"Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=MedicalManager;User Id=sa;Password=Pw@mm2021";
```